Proving that a graph containing a $T$-cycle also contains at least $T$ spanning trees
I have a task:

Prove that if graph contains a $T$-cycle, then it also contains at least $T$ spanning trees.

My solution: if we have other cycles than given in task, we can remove all their edges except one and therefore graph will stay connected. Then, we have a connected graph on $n$ vertices with a $t$-cycle (and it's an only cycle). Also we can notice that if we remove all the edges of cycle except one, we will get tree which will be the spanning tree of our graph, and if we do this witl all the edges of the cycle, we will get at least $T$ different spanning trees.
Now I know this is wrong, but don't know how to make a new working solution...  :(

The first assertion you make is wrong. Take a $T$-cycle and add to each vertex an edge to a vertex contained in another $T$-cycle. If you delete $T-1$ edges in the "middle" cycle the graph isn't connected anymore.

@schiepy is there probably a fix to my solution or it's completely incorrect ?  :(

@MishaLavrov sorry, i edited the post

I think maybe, for each instance of the cycle minus one edge, you should be able to extend it to a spanning tree (this is the part I'm not certain on).  Each such spanning tree must be different since it can't contain the removed edge of the cycle, so its overlap with the cycle must identify which edge you started out by removing.

I suppose you would probably need to assume the original graph is connected; otherwise, there's no possibly of having a spanning tree.

You have some good ideas; we'll delete some edges and remain spanning. We need the original graph to be connected; otherwise, it does not have a spanning tree. We will use the fact that a spanning tree of a graph is an edge minimal connected spanning subgraph.
Let $G$ be a connected graph with a $T$-cycle $C$, and let $G'$ be an edge minimal connected subgraph of $G$ containing $C$ with $V(G) = V(G')$. By the minimality of $G'$, deleting any edge of $G'$ not in $C$ disconnects $G'$, so $G'$ does not have any cycles other than $C$, as an edge in a cycle can be deleted while maintaining connectivity. Deleting any edge in $C$ from $G'$ thus forms a spanning acyclic subgraph of $G'$ and thus of $G$. Since $C$ has $T$ edges, this yields $T$ distinct spanning trees, as desired.
